# Android - How to achieve the same animation between activities (foxnews app)

Tags: android

I have no idea how to achieve the same animation effect we see in the android foxnews application. After displaying the splash screen, the view of the main activity is smoothly displayed. I would like to have the same animation between my splash screen and my dashboard activity.

Many thanks for any answers
T.

Comment: have you tried anything or done any research?

Comment: @Ian Actually I havent tried because i didnt find anything on my research, i am still reseaching on how to achieve that. Thanks, T.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

> This post features how to change Android’s default animation when
>   switching between Activities. Before reading the rest, please know
>   that the code that changes the standard animation be found at the API
>   Demo that comes with the Android SDK. But since there’s a lack of
>   proper documentation regarding this subject and it’s difficult to find
>   a place explaining it, here is a post that helps in aiding these two
>   problems.   So, the code to change the animation between two
>   Activities is very simple: just call the overridePendingTransition()
>   from the current Activity, after starting a new Intent. This method is
>   available from Android version 2.0 (API level 5), and it takes two
>   parameters, that are used to define the enter and exit animations of
>   your current Activity. Here’s an example:

```
//Calls a new Activity  
startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));  

//Set the transition -> method available from Android 2.0 and beyond  
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in,R.anim.push_up_out);
```

> These two parameters are resource IDs for animations defined with XML
>   files (one for each animation). These files have to be placed inside
>   the app’s res/anim folder. Examples of these files can be found at the
>   Android API demo, inside the anim folder. Let’s take a look at one of
>   these files (push_left_in.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

  <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>  
  <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />  

</set>
```

> As you can see on line 4, the screen is being translated from 100% of its parent width to 0 (meaning it is going from right to
>   left). Line 5 makes adds a fade effect to the animation. It’s really
>   simple to define a transition animation, it’s only a matter of calling
>   the correct attribute and assigning a value to it. For a list of
>   supported attributes for XML defined animations, click here. The 100%p
>   value indicates that we want this attribute to be applied 100%
>   relative to the parent. Other values could be 100% (without the “p“),
>   which means relative to self or just a numeric value without suffixes
>   making Android understand that we want this value to be interpreted as
>   absolute.   One thing to watch out for is that, this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

  <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>  

</set>
```

> Is different from this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

  <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="150"/>  
  <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="150"/>  

</set>
```

> The first line of code makes slides the View diagonally. The second one slides the View to the left and then up. So, one must
>   have in mind that all relative values are calculated based on the
>   current position of the View on the screen.

From [Android: Changing the animation between Activities](http://www.41post.com/3368/programming/android-changing-the-animation-between-activities)

It's how to make animation between activities but you have to change the animation xml files to do what you want.